# Trying to use Adapt based on LXC/LXD: couldn't find requested image

Tags: 16.04, lxc, lxd, adapt

I am trying to use Pitivi, latest version 0.97, on Ubuntu 16.04. It is available as flatpak, but I also found out about Adapt, by Dustin Kirkland, which sounds awesome and much more useful for me in the future:
http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2016/01/adapt-install-anything.html
https://www.ostechnix.com/adapt-run-app-version-ubuntu-version/

However, when I try it, I get this error:

```
root@ubuntu-laptop:~# adapt install -r yakkety -p pitivi
Creating adapt-ubuntu-yakkety
error: Couldn't find the requested image
```

I have been able to do a similar process on my own, by directly using lxc commands to create a Yakkety container, install Pitivi, and run it through ssh X.org redirection, so I know there is a viable Yakkety container template.

Has anyone successfully used Adapt? Why can't it find images?

Answer (score 1):

While looking for an answer for this question: [How use Adapt application](https://askubuntu.com/questions/904493/how-use-adapt-application) I ran into the same problems you mentioned.

I found this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/adapt/+bug/1575616) and used `sudo lxc remote remove images`, after which adapt works - I do not know if this fix is needed after every reboot or only after the first start - didn't test it. But makes it work.