# How use Adapt application

Tags: adapt

I have installed Adapt on Ubuntu 16.04 because I wanted to test it but it doesn't work. When I attempt command line execution I get:

```
ux@ux-VirtualBox:~$ lxc launch ubuntu:16.04
Creating precise-antelope
Starting precise-antelope
ux@ux-VirtualBox:~$ sudo adapt install -r wily -p apache2
Creating adapt-ubuntu-wily
error: Couldn't find the requested image
ux@ux-VirtualBox:~$
```

Seems like it needs further set up. There is no documentation to speak of; at least not that I can find.  Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I guess I figured it out. As far as I can asses it, there are two reasons it is not working:

1. **Bug 1575616 - error: Couldn't find the requested image**

   on my research I did find this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/adapt/+bug/1575616); while it describes a different problem, their solution works also for this problem, so I used: `sudo lxc remote remove images`; after which it worked nicely.
2. **apparently only supported releases are working**

   after using above fix, i tested your command and it failed with `error: not found (not a fingerprint, partial fingerprint (first 12 chars) or valid alias)`, so i poked around a bit with the different release code-names and found only the releases promoted on images.linuxcontainers.org working.

Hope this was helpful.